# Looping Through a JavaScript Generator Function

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to use a JavaScript generator function to get data from a database. But each step depends on the data that comes before it. I used an example from Wes Bos's ES6.io course, and in that, it does something similar and looks like

```
function ajax(url) {
    fetch(url).then(data => data.json()).then(data => dataGen.next(data))
}

function* steps() {
    console.log('fetching beers');
    const beers = yield ajax('http://api.react.beer/v2/search?q=hops&type=beer');
    console.log(beers);

    console.log('fetching user');
    const user = yield ajax('https://api.github.com/users/[user]');
    console.log(user);

    console.log('fetching fat joe');
    const fatJoe = yield ajax('https://api.discogs.com/artists/51988');
    console.log(fatJoe);
}

const dataGen = steps();
dataGen.next(); // kick it off
```

This works perfectly. The problem is that this depends on `dataGen` being globally available. I need to do all this inside a function. How can I call that `dataGen` in a loop but from another function? I'm looking for something similar to this:

```
function ajax(url) {
    fetch(url).then(data => data.json()).then(data => dataGen.next(data))
}

function* steps() {
    console.log('fetching beers');
    const beers = yield ajax('http://api.react.beer/v2/search?q=hops&type=beer');
    console.log(beers);

    console.log('fetching user');
    const user = yield ajax('https://api.github.com/users/[user]');
    console.log(user);

    console.log('fetching fat joe');
    const fatJoe = yield ajax('https://api.discogs.com/artists/51988');
    console.log(fatJoe);
}

function getInfo() {
    const dataGen = steps();
    for (const data of dataGen) {
        console.log(data);
    }
}
```

the `getInfo()` call ideally would be able to kick off the generator and be able to pass the data from each step on to the next one so that the data gets filled out correctly.

Any suggestions? I can use ES6 functions or functionality, but nothing higher.

Here's the output in the browser console for what happens when I try to do the second option, the one I'd love to get working:

[image]

Comment: And in wich sense is your "something like this" not working?

Comment: It's not working in that `dataGen` in the `ajax` function is not defined, and I can't get a way to pass the dataGen in to that `ajax` function at all.

Comment: @Jonasw check the edited question for the browser console output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The tricky part here is that the ajax function doesn't return anything, and if it did, it doesn't return the data right away.

So, to do what you are looking for, we have to move the promise logic into our loop. We can get rid of `ajax()` entirely and just use fetch directly:

```
function* steps() {
    const beers = yield fetch('http://api.react.beer/v2/search?q=hops&type=beer');
    const user = yield fetch('https://api.github.com/users/wesbos');
    const fatJoe = yield fetch('https://api.discogs.com/artists/51988');
}

function getInfo() {
  const dataGen = steps();
  for(const promise of dataGen) {
    promise.then(data => data.json()).then(data => {
      console.log(data);
      dataGen.next(data);
    });
  }
}

getInfo();
```

Comment: Thanks! This should help me get my real code up and running!

Comment: is there a way to pass data in for the first yield, but new data in for each `.next()` step after that?